# Mounting virtual disks on XenServer

Tags: mount, xenserver

I want to mount virtual disks on the XenServer host. I don't have any free space to create a partition [this way](http://opentodo.net/2012/10/create-local-iso-library-in-xen-server/) and want to use a virtual disk on local storage to store ISO images. I can't find any instructions on doing this.

Basically I need to mount the virtual disk below on the host, here is the listing for it from `xe vdi-list`...

```
uuid ( RO)                : 1b63af0e-4a32-473c-a20c-4fa408db201f
          name-label ( RW): iso_images
    name-description ( RW): ISO images from installation media
             sr-uuid ( RO): 71041776-39eb-c1ec-e7d1-eb4d047c70ed
        virtual-size ( RO): 21474836480
            sharable ( RO): false
           read-only ( RO): false
```

All the guides I can find on the subject involve different circumstances, such as the virtual disk being assigned to a VM.

Comment: https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/358515-mounting-a-guest-vm%E2%80%99s-hard-drive-vdi-on-the-host/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a sharable ISO library

- If someday you got more than one server, I suggest a ISO's CIFS's share, as it will allow you to enable the HA and it's easier to do and to update.

  xe-mount-iso-sr //server/share -o username=UserName,password=myPassword,domainname=domainname,sec=ntlmv2

  http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX123536
- If you have a local storage:

  **fdisk -l** (to find the disk), **mount /dev/sdXX /mnt/iso** and after **xe sr-create type=iso content-type=iso shared=false host-uuid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx name-label=ISO device-config:location=/mnt/iso device-config:legacy_mode=true**

Comment: I just have the one server for now.

Comment: @JohnTate Ok, never did a setup like you want, but did you tried the guide you gave, but with a USB stick in example ? as it will be detected as a new partition

Comment: I can't add USB storage to the machine.

Comment: @JohnTate Your storage you want to use is listed how, /dev/sdbX ?

Comment: @JohnTate I ask, as you can easilly just mount the storage you want to use, and issue a command like **xe sr-create type=iso content-type=iso shared=false host-uuid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx name-label=ISO device-config:location=/mnt/iso device-config:legacy_mode=true**

Comment: I don't know where the device file is. If I did I'd have done what you said. That is the problem, I want to mount a virtual disk on the host so I can store ISO images. I have nowhere else to put them.

Comment: Try a **fdisk -l** to list all disk, after you do a **mount /dev/sdbX /mnt/iso** and voila, you can do the command I gave.